# long dash does not get encoded properly after file_get_contents

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, file-get-contents, php-5.3

so I have this string

> "5. Before Dash—AfterDash"

inside a file

However, when opening the file using file_get_contents, the dash becomes converted to certain weird characters...Where's what it looks like if I echo the file_get_contents output

> "5. Before Dash�AfterDash"

How do I got about converting that � character to a valid long dash again in PHP? And how can I prevent further �  to appear in other characters as well?

this causes json_decode to fail when I try to json_decode the string?

Comment: Did you try setting your header to `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generalize Amal Murali's comment: Make sure the encoding of the text file, the encoding of the php file (both can be determined and changed by Notepad++ or other editors) and the output encoding (set by php's `header()` function as stated by Amal or by html meta tags) are the same. In case you work with any kind of database, make sure the connection uses the same encoding, too.

Comment: In case you have to output text that might contain special characters to the user (in html), consider using `htmlentities()`, too.